# add external nodes to ubuntu cloud?

Tags: server, cloud, vps, cluster

I have a website with a few traffic but 2 or 3 times in the year launch a campaign and this require a lot of bandwidth and process.

Actually have vps, in the campaign rent more vps and add this new nodes with a haproxy and synchronize the nodes.

I search a solution more automatic.

I try it with ubuntu cloud, but, ubuntu cloud accept external nodes or only accept nodes in the same local network?

If you have a another suggestion or solution for my problem is welcome.

Thank you and regards.

P.D.: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You could check out packages ran by load balancing.
http://freecode.com/projects/linuxvirtualserver/
Looks good but I don't know what your already running.